# Double tap required to follow link when virtual keyboard is shown on mobile Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, zendesk

I have a form. On mobile Chrome, when I am on one of the text fields for the form, the virtual keyboard shows up.
Then, I tap on the submit button (with the virtual keyboard still on) and this first tap will only hide the virtual keyboard, but not trigger the button's action. I will have to tap a second time, once the keyboard is hidden, in order to submit the form. 
This happens not only with the submit button, but with any link. I will have to tap once outside the keyboard to hide it, and again to actually follow the link.

This does not happen on other platforms or mobile browsers, like Safari or Firefox for Android. On these, taping on the submit button even with the virtual keyboard up, the form will be submitted directly.

I would like for the form to be able to be submitted on a single tap on mobile Chrome even when the keyboard is up.

Any idea of what the culprit may be?

Here's how the relevant HTML looks, although there's not much special about it:

```
<form id="new_request" data-form="" class="request-form" action="/hc/en-us/requests" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="HCY07rZcz/AvN8B4luwCgytDJJn/ZX6a7suZylBX2Jsl/ZPxoyaYRINA/jzBkNChuQadebM9noQ+GmDpijTA==">

    <div class="form-field string  required  request_subject">
      <label for="request_subject">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" name="request[subject]" id="request_subject" maxlength="75" size="150">
    </div>

    <div class="form-field text  required  request_description">
      <label for="request_description">Details</label>
      <textarea name="request[description]" id="request_description"></textarea>
    </div>

  <footer><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" data-track="hc_submit_login"></footer>

</form>
```

It is important to note that this happens on a Zendesk Help Center. For those not familiar with it, it is a platform for which I don't have access to much of the code. I have no access to any of the server-side, and most of the front end is already served for me by default, with the JS minified, although I can add my own JS on top of it.

Thank you!

Comment: no answer on this one? Still open?